# "subscribe()" is deprecated when using "of(false)"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use `of` but my editor is saying that it is deprecated. How can I get this to working using `of`?

```
  public save(): Observable<ISaveResult> | Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.item) {
      return this.databaseService.save(this.userId, this.item)
    }
    return of(false)
  }
```

```
  public componentSave() {
    const sub = this.userService
      .save()
      .subscribe(val => {
        // This callback shows the below error in the editor
      })
  }
```

When I use this, I get the following error in my editor:

```
@deprecated — Use an observer instead of a complete callback

'(next: null, error: (error: any) => void, complete: () => void): Subscription' is deprecated
Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
```

Comment: I do suspect the you are importing something from an old rxjs module path but you do need to provide a example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm using `Import {of} from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I think I found the problem. Change the return type of the save function from

```
public save(): Observable<ISaveResult> | Observable<boolean>
```

to

```
public save(): Observable<ISaveResult | boolean>
```

Comment: I am actually not using a return type. I'm just using it in the question. It is actually inferred from the return values.

Comment: Well then I go back to my original comment. You need to provide an example with the actual code that is broken.

Comment: If I don't inferre the return, it then works properly, thanks